# Android Navigate To Previous Activity Not Working?

Tags: android

I have added a Toolbar to my `AboutApplication` activity. I have also added a navigation button to this toolbar -

when this button is clicked, the application should navigate to the previous activity (`LoginActivity`).

I tried calling the finish inside method `onBackPressed()` and this did not work. I tried creating an `OnClickEventListener()` for the toolbar's `setNavigationOnClickListener()` - this did not work either.

Here is the code for my AboutApplication activity:

```
public class AboutApplicationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationOnClickListener myListener;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_application);

    myListener = new NavigationOnClickListener(this);
    myListener.setNextActivity(new LoginActivity());
    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutApplication);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.aboutApplicationToolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(myListener);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: if you finish an activity you won't be able to navigate back to it

Comment: it would be helpful to see Your method in the listener and in onBackPressed. From above code, there is nothing to see where You try to go back and/or finish actvity...

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse what you want with Navigation Design, you are requirement matches a lot like `Up navigation` provided by android, why do you want to make it around  when this feature is already provided to you.

if your  `AboutApplication` Activity comes from `LoginActivity` then you should apply Up Navigation provided my `Android` which know the best, let it handle it.

Things that you need to take care of while you are providing up navigation is that you properly define the child-parent structure in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your android project

```
<!-- Assuming this activity would be a parent -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.LoginActivity" ...>
    ...
</activity>
<!-- this would be your child activity in your case `AboutApplicationActivity`  -->
<activity
    android:name=".AboutApplicationActivity"
  >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.LoginActivity" />

</activity>
```

now in your child activity things you need to make sure is this,

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // without support library 

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // support library
```

and offcours by now you know where does this goes

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

if you have hard time importing `NavUtils.java`, than write its fully qualified name `android.support.v4.app.NavUtils`

for more details use android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html),